# Flyway: how to prevent accidentally running migrations from developer on a central database?

Tags: database, spring-boot, flyway

When I debug against a (central) database, Flyway can update the database schema. This happens when my local application runs on a development branch which is further ahead than the deployed application.
Running the local application will then invoke migration scripts on the central database. In the worst case, this might update a production database of course.

Another scenario is one where 2 developers work against 1 development database with test-data. Both developers are working on different features and both are modifying the schema. When one developer updates the db, the other is (probably) confronted with a checksum issue, and otherwise surprised by the changes made.

I'm thinking about a solution to such problems.

Of course, there are some solutions outside of Flyway, like only connecting to throw-away databases, or preventing access to important db's.

I'm interested in which options Flyway offers.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options, which seems to be useful in your cases.

For the first one, you can set the `target` property with the same version your DB has, to prevent Flyway to update it.

For the second case with 2 developers working simultaneously with the same DB instance, you can try to turn off the `validateOnMigrate` property to avoid validation failures or the `ignoreMissingMigrations` to ignore the migrations some of the developers doesn't have yet.

[Here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate) you can find all available via console properties for migration task. You didn't specify, haw exactly you run the Flyway, if it's done vie Spring Boot, then not all this properties are available, just some of them - you can find it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) under the Flyway section.

But for most cases, I think, the best solution is to simply turn Flyway migrations off during the development and debugging if it's possible and use for the delivery of ready features.